# Using Python to find keywords in documents within folder structures

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I was wondering if anyone knew how to find keywords in documents and then export those words into an excel document.

For example, I have a document named "test" in Folder A > Folder B. I am wanting to go into that folder, find the document named "test", open that file, find a keyword "test", and then export "test" into an excel document.

The reason I am asking is that there is thousands of folders that this needs to be done for. I've looked at other solutions and they suggested pdfminer, but I'm not sure how to run that across many folders/subfolders and export the key word into an excel document.

This is what I have so far. It's able to convert a PDF to text and then find a keyword from the text. Not sure how I am able to export this data into an excel file/column. Thanks

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Stafford_Capital.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    fstr = ''
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,    password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        str = retstr.getvalue()
        fstr += str

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return fstr

print convert_pdf_to_txt("test.pdf")

string = convert_pdf_to_txt("test.pdf")
lines = list(filter(bool,string.split('\n')))
custData = {}
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if 'Lead:' in lines[i]:
        custData['Name'] = lines[i+2]
    elif 'Date:Date:Date:Date:' in lines[i]:
        custData['Fund Manager'] = lines[i+2]
    elif 'Priority:' in lines[i]:
        custData['Industry'] = lines[i+2]
        custData['Date'] = lines[i+1]
        custData['Deal Size']= lines [i+3]
    elif 'DEAL QUALIFYING MEMORANDUM' in lines[i]:
        custData['Owner'] = lines[i+2]
    elif 'Fund Manager' in lines[i]:
        custData['Investment Type'] = lines [i+2]
print custData

row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, descrip in custData.iteritems():
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row+1, col, descrip)
    col += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this.  Post the code you have and indicate what part is giving you trouble.  (Note that make sense out of the contents of pdf files can be difficult and, if the documents are actually scans rather than printed from a text-based program, can be impossible).

Comment: Hi I edited my post to include my code. I'm not sure how to export the keyword into an excel file and repeat it for hundreds of pdfs. Thanks!